# Offset values after a certain index in a pandas serie

Tags: python, pandas

I create series from json data, it is a dictionary like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    5: 10,
    2: 1,
    10: 7,
}

serie = pd.Series(data).sort_index()
```

I want to offset all values after (and including) a certain index, for example, if `offset` is 5 and `index` is 3, I want this to be equivalent to this:

```py
# There is no data at 3, so le'ts interpolate it and add it
[y] = np.interp([3], serie.index, serie.values)

data = {
    3: y + 5,
    5: 10 + 5,
    2: 1, # index is smalled that 3, do not touch
    10: 7 + 5,
}

serie = pd.Series(data).sort_index()

print(serie)
```

If the index does not exist, I interpolate it before offsetting it. Also I mention that my data is a dictionary at its origin, don't hesitate to suggest a better way to alter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) and modify in place:

```
out = (serie
       .reindex(serie.index.union([3]))
       .interpolate('index')
      )

out[out.index>=3] += 5

print(out)
```

Output:

```
2      1.0
3      9.0
5     15.0
10    12.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you regarding the interpolation part. The offsetting is easy, though, use mask:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    5: 10,
    2: 1,
    10: 7,
}

serie = pd.Series(data).sort_index()

index = 3
offset = 5

# create the desired index if it does not yet exist
if not (serie.index == 3).any():
    serie[3] = np.interp([3], serie.index, serie.values)

# offsetting
serie = serie.\
    mask(
        serie.index >= index,
        serie + offset
    )

serie

Out[44]: 
2         1
5        15
10       12
3     [9.0]
dtype: object
```